# WAMP - How to arrange folders to hide some php files and images?

Tags: php, .htaccess

At the moment my folders are structured like so:

- MySite

  - .htaccess
  - index.php +other .php/.html files
  - php/
  - images/
  - scripts/
  - stylesheets/

The php folder stores scripts only, no visual pages.
I am web hosting with Hostgator, and there is a public_html folder which is visible to everyone. I want to hide my php/ and images/ folders so clients can't see their content. I want to hide the php scripts especially as I don't want bots be able to scour my code and find my email address where I handle email form processing. I am developing it in WAMP and I would like a similar structure that Hostgator has so I can separate my public and private files. Can I do it with .htaccess, or is there a better way?

So I want it something like this:

- MySite

  - .htaccess
  - public_html

    - index.php +other .php/.html files
    - scripts/
    - stylesheets/
  - php/
  - images/

Also, is it possible to hide JavaScript files, or is it impossible as they are requested by clients when they are included on a page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea with this:

- MySite

  - .htaccess
  - public_html

    - index.php +other .php/.html files
    - scripts/
    - stylesheets/
  - php/
  - images/

where *php/* and *images/* are hidden.

You can `include()` files that are there, but if public_html is your webroot, then the world can't see them. You'd have to use a PHP script to read and output your images though, because of the hidden nature of that directory.

You cannot hide your JS or CSS because the browser must be able to read them.

I'm not 100% certain, but you might need to move or copy .htaccess into public_html